# CSS Media query and SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Upon resizing the window of the browser, I am trying to change the "fill" of the SVG element. I have experimented with other values, such as "visibility: hidden;" and the element does in fact hide.  However it doesn't seem to respond to trying to change the fill. Take a look at the code. Any ideas?

SVG:

```
<svg>
<rect class="d" x="150" y="150" width="500" height="350"
    rx="40" ry="40"
    style="fill: blue;
           fill-opacity: .7;"/>

</svg>
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 451px){
.d {
fill: red;
  }  
}
```

Comment: The inline style has higher priority than the media query, you can either use !important in your media query css or stylize your rect by `.d { fill: blue; }`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `style` is overriding the `class`. Try setting the class `d` to the original values you have set in your `style` tag, then remove that style tag.

Comment: Not sure why it works this way, but that worked. Instead of inline styling, i changed the fill in the css file and updated the color in the media query.

Answer (score 0):

inline style priority is higher than class. So you should set style in class normal and media query.